# React Native MaterialIcons are not rendered correctly

Tags: react-native, material-ui, material-icons

Material Icons library render icons correctly in development mode, but it seems corrupted in production. It renders a question mark which means that icon name is invalid. But it is not.
[image: It renders a question mark which means that icon name is invalid. But it is not.]

Comment: have you checked that you are loading your fonts then launching the app? also you added them in xcode to the files as per the documentation?

Comment: I have built before, there was no problem, it occurred in the last update without any update to library or any other change

Answer (score 0):

Some of the icons are visible, but others are not and you say that this issue is from the last update so I think this is related to the names of the icons, take a look at this ref:

- https://github.com/oblador/react-native-vector-icons/issues/1003
- [React-native vector icons shown as question mark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45395734/react-native-vector-icons-shown-as-question-mark)
- https://github.com/oblador/react-native-vector-icons/issues/697
- [Expo Icons show question marks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65868743/expo-icons-show-question-marks)

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue while implementing bottom tab navigation bar and I fixed using below steps.

Install react-native-vector-icons

```
npm install --save react-native-vector-icons
```

Navigate to the react-native-vector-icons folder within the node_modules/react-native-vector-icons/Fonts directory. Once you are there, take the Font folder and drag it into the root directory of your Xcode project. Ensure that you follow a process similar to the provided image for better clarity.

[image: Xcode directory structure after copying that Font folder.]

Next, open your Info.plist file and copy the content provided below:

```
<key>UIAppFonts</key>
    <array>
        <string>AntDesign.ttf</string>
        <string>Entypo.ttf</string>
        <string>EvilIcons.ttf</string>
        <string>Feather.ttf</string>
        <string>FontAwesome.ttf</string>
        <string>FontAwesome5_Brands.ttf</string>
        <string>FontAwesome5_Regular.ttf</string>
        <string>FontAwesome5_Solid.ttf</string>
        <string>FontAwesome6_Brands.ttf</string>
        <string>FontAwesome6_Regular.ttf</string>
        <string>FontAwesome6_Solid.ttf</string>
        <string>Foundation.ttf</string>
        <string>Ionicons.ttf</string>
        <string>MaterialIcons.ttf</string>
        <string>MaterialCommunityIcons.ttf</string>
        <string>SimpleLineIcons.ttf</string>
        <string>Octicons.ttf</string>
        <string>Zocial.ttf</string>
        <string>Fontisto.ttf</string>
    </array>
```

last step is to create react-native.config.js using below code:

```
  module.exports = {
    dependencies: {
      'react-native-vector-icons': {
        platforms: {
          ios: null,
        },
      },
    },
  };
```

Afterward, execute npm install and pod install once more to resolve the issue of encountering a question mark.

IF you have any doubts then you can follow below reference which is very helpful.

Ref: [github.com/oblador/react-native-vector-icons](https://github.com/oblador/react-native-vector-icons)